# Capacitors connected in parallel with a switch attached

Tags: capacitance

[image]

What does it mean when they say capacitor reaching equilibrium?

Answer (score 1):

"A capacitor reaches equilibrium" just means:

The capacitor has reached a steady state, and there is no charging/discharging current flowing anymore.

Answer (score 0):

To say Capacitor C1 reaches "equilibrium" simply means the voltage across the capacitor has  stopped changing (i.e. the capacitor has stopped being charged by the battery) so that its voltage is now equal to (in equilibrium with) the battery voltage. At that point current will no longer flow to the capacitor.

Hope this helps.